# Правила написання "з" та "зі"

Tags: вживання-слів

Як правильно "працювати з зображеннями" чи "працювати із зображеннями" ?
Річ у тім що я не можу знайти точних правил

[ukr-mova.in.ua](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/orfografiya/mulozvuchnist-z,-iz,-zi,-zo.-chastuna-1) каже що "зі" пишеться між приголосними / перед "с" і "ш" / між групами приголосних...

[uk.wikipedia.org](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96#%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2_%D0%B7_%E2%80%94_%D1%96%D0%B7_%E2%80%94_%D0%B7%D1%96_(%D0%B7%D0%BE)) каже "Зі вживається перед сполученням приголосних початку слова, зокрема коли початковими виступають з, с, ш, щ тощо, незалежно від паузи та закінчення попереднього слова: Ви зустріли ворога з палаючою ненавистю в очах, зі зброєю в руках (Ю. Яновський). Зі снігу каші не звариш (Прислів'я). Учень іде зі школи додому."

Допоможіть мені знайти підходяще правило, та назвіть ресурс, звідки Ви отримали таке правило.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[«Український правопис» 2019, § 25.3, с. 20](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=20):

> 3. **Зі** вживаємо, якщо буквосполучення наступного слова має початкові **з**, **с**, **ш**, **шч** та ін., незалежно від закінчення попереднього слова чи паузи: *Ви зустріли ворога… **зі** зброєю в руках* (Ю. Яновський); *Балада **зі** знаком запитання* (І. Драч); *Бере книжку **зі** стола* (Леся Українка); ***Зі** школи на майдан вивалила дітвора* (А. Головко); *Прибув **зі** Львова*.
>
> У позиції перед деякими буквосполученнями варіанти **із** та **зі** можуть
> бути взаємозамінними, пор.: *Устав разом **із** сходом сонця* і *Устав разом **зі** сходом сонця*.
>
> Примітка. Трапляються відхилення від поданих правил уживання прийменника **з** та його варіантів **із**, **зі**, що спричинено вимогами ритмомелодики або мовними вподобаннями автора.
>
> **Зо** як фонетичний варіант прийменника **зі** завжди вживаємо із
> числівниками *два*, *три*: *Позичив **зо** дві сотні*; *Проспав **зо** три години* та із займенником *мною*: *Він був **зі** (**зо**) мною*.